# building FSA in prolog

Tags: prolog, finite-automata

I am asked to represent a FSA in prolog.

- An fsa is a list of states.
- A state is a structure with the functor state and 3 arguments: a name, a list of
  transitions, and either yes or no to indicate whether the state is accepting or
  not.
- A transition is a structure with the functor transition and 2 arguments: from,
  a character, and to, a state name.

**Our FSAs do not have epsilon moves.**

`nondfsa(FSA)` is true if FSA is non-deterministic. Finish nondfsa. Hint: use a
helper predicate, `nondstate(State)`, that is true if State has non-deterministic
transitions. You can add clauses for the predicates.`

I am given the answer as follows:

```
nondfsa([Hstate | _ ])
    :- nondstate(Hstate).
nondfsa([ _ | Tailstates]) :-
    nondfsa(Tailstates).

nondstate(state( _ , Transitions, _ )):-
    member(transition(Char, To1), Transitions),
    member(transition(Char, To2), Transitions),
    not(To1 = To2).
```

can anyone help explain to me what each predicate is doing? I am very confused on what exactly these lines are translating to.

I understand An fsa without epsilon moves is non-deterministic if at least one state has more than one transition with the same character.
I just don't understand what is going on in this code.

Comment: What does *I am given the answer* mean? Was it your assignment to come up with that answer, or did they provide it in class and you're supposed to analyze it?

Comment: @lurker it is for a practice final exam and the task is to come up with the code and to check your work they provide you the correct answer. I just don't quite understand how they came up with it and what exactly it's doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The presented code is very straightforward and it would be good to learn to "read through" a Prolog predicate.

```
nondfsa([Hstate | _ ]) :-
    nondstate(Hstate).
nondfsa([ _ | Tailstates]) :-
    nondfsa(Tailstates).
```

This is a very common Prolog pattern which recursively checks every element of a list for something. `nondfsa/1` checks each element of the list. If *any* of them is a non-deterministic state (according to `nondstate/1`), then `nondfsa/1` succeeds, meaning the FSA is non-deterministic. If `nondstate/1` does not succeed for *any* element in the given list, then `nondfsa/1` will fail. The first clause checks the head of the list. The second clause skips the head and checks the rest of the list. In the recursive call, Prolog starts back at the first clause again, so it simply checks the next element via `nondstate/1`.

```
nondstate(state( _ , Transitions, _ )):-
    member(transition(Char, To1), Transitions),
    member(transition(Char, To2), Transitions),
    not(To1 = To2).
```

`nondstate/1` succeeds if the given `state/3` is found to be non-deterministic per some definition which depends only upon the transitions of that state. If you read through your `nondstate/1` predicate, you can see what this is. The predicate succeeds if:

1. I can obtain a member of the list of transitions
2. I can obtain another member of the list of transitions using the *same character* (this will always succeed at least once, using the same member as in #1)
3. The destination state for each of the two members are different

In other words, a state is non-deterministic if there's one character that has transition to at least two different states.